# Stop Focus on input onChangeMonthYear of JqueryUI DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

In my iOS device I got this problem with `JQuery UI Datepicker`.

The problem I am facing is like I click on this button to go for prev or next month,

[image]

I got scrolled to the text-box(input) back. So this affect that in landscape mode where height is smaller, if user wants to change month than he has to scroll back to up where that month or year changing button exist.

I tried to use `onChangeMonthYear` event but what should I do in that is not clear. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/vzmpdx5z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that fiddle would work perfectly.

If we disable the textbox and make it enable it, It would not focus on the textbox,

Thus your problem would be solved.

Just write below code in your JS.

```
onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, element) {
            // To Prevent focus on change of month or year
            element.input.prop("disabled", true);
            window.setTimeout(function () {
            element.input.prop("disabled", false);
        }, 100);
},
```